# How to keep track of what question user is responding to?

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, messenger

Some questions my messenger chatbot is asking require textual input. In the [button template](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/template/button/) I can set the **payload** so I know what exactly user chosen and handle it based on that. But with textual responses I need to filter if user answer is somehow related to "Change address, Billing, Returns, etc." **For example:**

```
bot-question: What is your new phone number?
user-answer: +123 123 12345
```

And now in the back-end I'm doing this:

```
if(user-answer in_array('billing keywords') {
    // code
} elseif (user-answer in_array('delivery keywords')) {
    // code
} elseif (user-answer in_array('payments keywords')) {
    // code
} elseif (user-answer in_array('change-phone-number keywords')) {
    // Finally got where I wanted 
}
```

Isn't it possible to somehow add some tag to bot-question, so I would already know that the answer will be related to `change-phone-number keywords`? For example like this:

```
  "template_type" => "text",
  "text" => "What is your new phone number?",
  "payload" => "changing_phone_number"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was impossible to get some `postback` from a normal text message, so what I did, I created additional columns:

- expecting_billing_info
- expecting_phone_number_update
- etc.

And I set it to `0` by default, but when bot asks a question like:

> Would you like to change your phone number?

I set it to `1` and when user types it in I do:

```
if (expecting_phone_number_update == 1) {
    // 1. get the message
    // 2. Check if it's correct phone number format
    // 3. Reply based on 2. and update phone number
} elseif (expecting_billing_info == 1) {
    // ...
}
```

This is not perfectly clean solution, but it does the work. Let's hope messenger will release this postback feature one day for normal messages as well! :)